# Import and Export line spacing in VSCode using Beautify.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have been using [VSCodeBeautify](https://github.com/HookyQR/VSCodeBeautify) to clean up some of my TypeScript files it works great for most cases with the exception of imports and exports.

Current Behavior on save

```
import {
    AccountsModel
} from '../models/accounts';
```

Desired Behavior

```
import { AccountsModel } from '../models/accounts';
```

I tried creating a `.jsbeautifyrc` file in the root of the project, but it does not seem to be getting picked up.

```
{
  "preserve_newlines": true,
  "max_preserve_newlines": 2
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up using.

```
{
    "brace_style": "collapse-preserve-inline"
}
```

Works great!